# What is '..' really represent for?

Tags: symlink, path

1. centos version :8.5.2111
2. I am now at this pwd : `/tmp/new/`
3. I need to create a soft link between
   `/home/chenchen/Videos/` and `/tmp/softlink`
4. Here is my command: `ln -s /home/chenchen/Videos/ ../softlink`
5. Result:This softlink appeared at `/home/chenchen/softlink`,but i suppose it to appear at `/tmp/softlink`
6. Apparently,'`..`' represented for `/home/chenchen` in step.4 command
7. However,when i use `double-tab` at this moment :
   `ln -s /home/chenchen/Videos/ ../`    ,It shows me some files under  `/tmp/`  At this moment,`..` represent for `/tmp`
8. Question:On step4 and step7,why `..` has different meanings in almost the same command?

Comment: Is `/tmp/new` a symbolic link to a subdirectory of `/home/chenchen`?

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: I am using bash shell

Comment: Sorry to bother you .This mistake caused by my fault. The /tmp/new is already a softlink to /home/chenchen/Videos ,and this is why .. was interpreted as /home/chenchen .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't that `..` has different meanings, it is that the shell is interpreting `..` incorrectly.

The issue here is that the shell thinks it knows what directory you are in, but if one of the paths in the shell's pwd is a symlink, and `..` traverses that symlink, the shell will remove the path component to generate the new directory, but this may actually not be correct, and actually traversing `..` will give different results.

You can see this more directly if you compare the output of the shell built in `pwd` with the external `/bin/pwd`.  In bash, you can also use shell builtin `pwd -P` to get the real path.